# app name is appended to the table name in django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

When I try to fetch data from the table, the app name is appended to the table name and displays an error. Following is my code.

```
from models import open_cart

class test(APIView):

  def get(self,request,format=None):
    values = open_cart.objects.get()
```

My app name that I have defined in installed_apps is 'MyApp'.My table name is 'open_cart'. table name in the query goes as MyApp_open_cart instead of open_cart. 
the error message that i get is **relation "untitled_open_cart" does not exist**

Comment: post your models and also the settings file

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Appending the app name to the table name is default behavior in Django. If you want to use a custom table name add it in the [Meta class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#meta-options).

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    class Meta(CommonInfo.Meta):
        db_table = 'student_info'
```

Refer to the [official Django Model Meta options documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Django Append app name before the model name by default. If we want to use our custom table name then it will have to mention in side the Meta class.

```
class Open_cart(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'open_cart'
```